# Bootstrap Nave Tabs & Knockout Click Event

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js, data-binding, tabs

**This is an issue that I spent a lot of time debugging; *I will answer this question myself as it is a strange anomaly.***

I am using Bootstrap's `nav-tabs` component for creating tabs with different types of data -- which, upon clicking a tab, will call an appropriate function to issue a request for the data.

I, also, am using Knockout to bind the function-call to each list item in the `nav-tab` `ul` and using a `setTimeout` to mimic an AJAX call.

---

*The issue is:*

When I click on a tab other than the `first-child` the correct `tab-pane` appears as usual -- however, within a matter of time the current tab's `tab-pane` gets reset to the `first-child` `tab-pane` (as if you clicked on the first tab). I can even see this via the element inspector.

It seems as though there is a conflict between Bootstrap/jQuery `data-toggle="tab"` and Knockout's `data-bind="click: myFunction"`.

**HTML**

---

```
<ul id="clientDetailsTab" class="nav nav-tabs" data-tabs="tabs">

    <li class="active">
        <a href="#detailGeneralInfo" data-toggle="tab" data-bind="click: ClientSearch.details.getGeneralInfo">General Information</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#detailAddress" data-toggle="tab" data-bind="click: ClientSearch.details.getAddress">Address</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#detailPhone" data-toggle="tab" data-bind="click: ClientSearch.details.getPhone">Phone</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#detailRelations" data-toggle="tab" data-bind="click: ClientSearch.details.getRelations">Relations</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#detailCritical" data-toggle="tab" data-bind="click: ClientSearch.details.getCriticalInfo">Critical Info</a>
    </li>

</ul>
<div class="tab-content" data-bind="with: ClientSearch.selectedClient">

    <div id="detailGeneralInfo" class="tab-pane active" style="border: solid 1px blue;">
        General: <span data-bind="text: _general.birthDate"></span>
    </div>
    <div id="detailAddress" class="tab-pane" style="border: solid 1px orange;">
        Address: <span data-bind="text: _address.more"></span>
    </div>
    <div id="detailPhone" class="tab-pane" style="border: solid 1px purple;">
        Phone: <span data-bind="text: _phone.more"></span>
    </div>
    <div id="detailRelations" class="tab-pane" style="border: solid 1px red;">
        Relations: <span data-bind="text: _relations.more"></span>
    </div>
    <div id="detailCritical" class="tab-pane" style="border: solid 1px green;">
        Critical: <span data-bind="text: _critical.more"></span>
    </div>

</div>
```

**JavaScript**

---

```
function GetGeneralInformation() {...}  // THIS one actually makes an ajax request

// THIS one uses a setTimeout to mimic an ajax request
function GetAddress() {
    var selected = selectedClient()
        , clientId = selected.clientId;

    setTimeout(function () {
        selectedClient($.extend(
            (selectedClient()), {
                _address: { more: 'GetAddress' }
            }
        ));
    }, (1000 * 4.5));
    console.log('GOT ADDRESS', selected);
}

function GetPhone() {...}  // same as above
function GetRelations() {...}  // same as above
function GetCriticalInformation() {...}  // same as above
```

So why is the `active` class being added to the correct `tab-pane` upon click and then resetting the `first-child` `tab-pane`'s class to `active`...?

As I noted earlier, I will provide the answer below...

Answer (score 0):

**Here's what was causing the issue:**

In the question I noted the JavaScript:

```
function GetGeneralInformation() {...}  // THIS one actually makes an ajax request

// THIS one uses a setTimeout to mimic an ajax request
function GetAddress() {
    var selected = selectedClient()
        , clientId = selected.clientId;

    setTimeout(function () {
        selectedClient($.extend(
            (selectedClient()), {
                _address: { more: 'GetAddress' }
            }
        ));
    }, (1000 * 4.5));
    console.log('GOT ADDRESS', selected);
}

function GetPhone() {...}  // same as above
function GetRelations() {...}  // same as above
function GetCriticalInformation() {...}  // same as above
```

If I simply comment out the `setTimeout` then I experience no issues:

```
function GetAddress() {
    var selected = selectedClient()
        , clientId = selected.clientId;

    //setTimeout(function () {
        selectedClient($.extend(
            (selectedClient()), {
                _address: { more: 'GetAddress' }
            }
        ));
    //}, (1000 * 4.5));
    console.log('GOT ADDRESS', selected);
}
```

Also, if you change the timeout duration, you'll notice the issue behaves accordingly.

**I hope this helps some poor soul out there as lost as I was** -- beware the timeout.

--Cheers